# My Serial timout-function does work on the first call, but not on the second

Tags: arduino, serial-port, atmega

I want to read te serial and have made a timeout function.

I want to read letters or the date but have the program continue if nothing has been send.

I already worked on this problem almost the whole day, and could narrow it down to a possible solution. But i dont know why this is working.

I put in a "Serial.flush()", and now the program works as expected. If this is not put in, the second call to "waitForSerial..." is not entered, or immediately exited. 
Also and alternative that works, is the two lines in the while-loop after flush.

I already ruled out that it could be a problem of: eclipse, the programmer, bad serial connection.

**UPDATE:**
If the println before flush is not there, than it does not work either. WTF?

**UPDATE2:**
I think i know the cause:
I send serial data with "\r\n". The letter lets my timeOutfunction exit and proceed with the code. With the loop and Serial.read() i want to empty the receive buffer. While emptying it, it is then empty but still beeing filled with the incoming serial.data. Then the loop is exited, but the receive buffer is still beeing filled. And when the code is executed at "waitForSerialAndTimeOut(15000)" the receivebuffer was filled unnoticed and therefore the function lets the code beeing normaly as there would have been valid input.

The new receiverbuffer emtpying function:

```
void flushReceiveBuffer(){
    while(Serial.available()){
        Serial.read();
        delayMicroseconds(200); //wait for the buffer that may be filled simultaneously
    }
}
```

```
#include "arduino.h"


unsigned long serialStartTime;

bool waitForSerialAndTimeOut(unsigned long timeOut){
    serialStartTime = millis();
    while(!Serial.available()){
        if(millis() - serialStartTime > timeOut){
            Serial.println("Serial input timed out");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void checkForAndSetNewTime(){
    while(Serial.available()){
        Serial.read();
    }

    Serial.println(F("Send a letter to set date"));

    if(waitForSerialAndTimeOut(3000))
        return;

    Serial.println("continuing");
    Serial.flush(); //WHY is the second "waitForSerial..." not working WITHOUT this flush?

    while(Serial.available()){
//      Serial.print("Serial consumed: ");
//      Serial.println(Serial.read(),DEC);    //This works too instead of flush!!!

        Serial.read();
    }

    Serial.println(F("Set the current date with day month year hour minute day-of-the-week"));


    if(waitForSerialAndTimeOut(15000))
        return;

    Serial.println("parsing");

    int minute = 99;
    int hour, year, month, day;

    day   = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, 1);
    month = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, 1);
    year  = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, 1) - 2000;

    hour   = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, 1);
    minute = Serial.parseInt(SKIP_ALL, 1);


    Serial.print("read: ");
    Serial.print(day);
    Serial.print(".");
    Serial.print(month);
    Serial.print(".");
    Serial.print(year);
    Serial.print(" ");

    Serial.print(hour);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(minute);
    Serial.println();
}


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(57600);

    delay(300);

    Serial.println(__DATE__);
    Serial.println(__TIME__);


    checkForAndSetNewTime();


}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: what Arduino is it?

Comment: It is a atmega328 and i am using eclipse.

Comment: more details about Eclipse, please. what plugin? Sloeber?

Comment: Version: Neon (4.6)
Build id: I20160606-1100

CDT C/C++ Development Tools

AVR-Plugin 2.4.2

You think this is an Eclipse issue?

Comment: I got closer to a solution: See my edited text above.

Comment: What do you mean by working or not working? What does your program output now? What do you expect?

Comment: Some more Update on the orignal post. I made a different loop, that emtpys the receive buffer.

Comment: please include your serial log if available, and show what you expect vs what you get with the different programs